# Underscore.js _.reduce() to return objects

Tags: javascript, object, underscore.js, reduce

I'm attempting to create a list of how many stores carry a given item from an array of stores. Individual objects in the `stores` array can contain a bunch of different properties (name, location, etc.), but I'm just looking to pick out the inventory (an array of item types they carry, not actual stock numbers -- looks like `['hammers', 'wrenches', 'screw drivers'`), and create an object with each item as a property containing a count.

```
//simplified stores array for reference
stores = [
       { name: "Al's Hardware", inventory: ['hammers', 'wrenches'] },
       { name: "House Depot", inventory: ['wrenches', 'hammers', 'screw drivers'] },
       { name: "Grove Hardware", inventory: ['wrenches', 'screw drivers'] }
];

var itemCount = _(stores).chain()
   .map(store => store.inventory)
   .flatten()
   .reduce((list, item) => list[item] = (list[item] || 0) + 1, {})
   .value();

console.log(itemCount['hammers']); //Expected: 2; Actual: undefined
console.log(itemCount); //Expected: object containing all names and values; Actual: 1
```

Not sure yet what I'm doing wrong, but I'm guessing it has to do with how I'm trying to use _.reduce(). However, at this point I'm kind of lost, so I'm not sure what to try next.

I'm certain this is the structure I want (I'm not looking for work-arounds), I'm just curious what I'm doing to make reduce apparently break, and how I can change it to work correctly so it'll give me back something that looks like

```
{'hammers': 2,
'wrenches': 3,
'screw drivers': 2}
```

etc.

Comment: Could you please share what `stores` looks like?

Comment: Edited to include `stores`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)'s callback should return the `initialValue` i.e. the empty object, if you don't use the arrow function what you did is like

```
.reduce(function (list, item) {
  return list[item] = (list[item] || 0) + 1
}, {})
```

It should be

```
.reduce(function (list, item) {
  list[item] = (list[item] || 0) + 1
  return list
}, {})
```

And if you want a one liner you can use

```
.reduce((list, item) => (list[item] = (list[item] || 0) + 1, list), {})
```

Example

```js
console.log(['a', 'a', 'b', 'c'].reduce((list, item) => (list[item] = (list[item] || 0) + 1, list), {}))
```

Comment: This is good. Unfortunately, the one-liner you included at the end didn't work for me, but you can replace the boilerplate by writing `.reduce((list, item) => {list[item] = (list[item] || 0) + 1; return list;}, {});`